# Ubuntu Server 16.04 Available RAM

Tags: server, ram

I just installed Ubuntu Server with RAID 0 used 2 2TB drives. I run free -m and displayed like this:

[image]

So what is different between free memory and available memory? Is that normal?
Thank you

Comment: Pretty sure this is a duplicate, but can't seem to find it right now. As far as available vs free, yes that is normal. Free is actual free bytes in RAM. Available is what the kernel has available as free to allocate to processes.

Comment: Thank you, so you mean that "available" is actual free memory, right?

Comment: I'm sure you know, but free reports memory usage, not disk usage.  I only say this because you indicated what drives you install which is irrelevant to free.